# Check if login information is correct for remote database

Tags: javascript, couchdb, pouchdb

So I'm just looking to have a sign in of sorts for the app I'm currently developing. For now there's just one username dbreader, but the user will have to input the password to access the remote database (couchdb) and sync. What would be the best way to check if the password they've provided is correct so that I can return failed to login or login success. Send a sync request to an empty database using the inputted password and see if it throws authentication failed?

Answer (score 3):

You can validate credentials by sending a request to the _session endpoint.

Basically, you create a session cookie. If it fails, you will receive a 401 HTTP Status Code. Otherwise, you will receive an 200 HTTP Status Code with your roles,name and your cookie.

More information can be found [in the doc](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.0/api/server/authn.html)

```js
$.ajax({
  url:"http://localhost:5984/_session",
  method:"POST",
  dataType:"json",
  data: {
    name:"test",
    password:"test"
  }
}).done(function(res){
  console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
}).fail(function(err){
  console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: No way to access the session endpoint with pouchdb from what I can see

Comment: You can search for a PouchDB plugin that would do so but if you can't find one, you can simply do the request manually using Ajax requests.

Comment: The plugins available aren't lightweight enough for a simple check of whether the password is correct or not. They put in all sorts of features I don't want. I tried using Ajax and always got 500 internal server errors, not sure why and not very helpful as to finding the problem, I fiddled with it for a couple of hours. Any advice on identifying the cause of that would be great. Currently I've reverted to just checking the server response when I try to connect to a database with an inputted password

Comment: Which library are you using to make your requests? I'll provide you a working example

Comment: I was just using jquery, I tried native js as well. Here's the code I was using with my server ip changed to *'s.   $.ajax({
    url : 'http://**.***.***.***:5984/_session',
    data : JSON.stringify({'name': username, 'password': password}),
    contentType : "application/json", 
    type : 'POST'
  });

Comment: Try this working example : http://jsbin.com/faraxijeya/1/edit?js,console

Comment: Unfortunately that js bin endlessly loads for me, it's often a problem with that site, could you put it in a jsfiddle instead?

Comment: what if you already have a session cookie? how can you verify if it's still good? what if it goes bad while syncing?